# What is causing this: Cannot jump from switch statement to this case label

Tags: objective-c, switch-statement, ios9

This is a switch statement that I am getting errors on:

```
        switch (transaction.transactionState) {

        case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:

            // show wait view here
            statusLabel.text = @"Processing...";
            break;

        case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:

            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];

            // remove wait view and unlock iClooud Syncing
            statusLabel.text = @"Done!";

            NSError *error = nil;
            [SFHFKeychainUtils storeUsername:@"IAPNoob01" andPassword:@"whatever" forServiceName: kStoredData updateExisting:YES error:&error];

            // apply purchase action  - hide lock overlay and
            [oStockLock setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            // do other thing to enable the features

            break;

        case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:

            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];

            // remove wait view here
            statusLabel.text = @"";
            break;

        case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:

            if (transaction.error.code != SKErrorPaymentCancelled) {
                NSLog(@"Error payment cancelled");
            }
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
            // remove wait view here
            statusLabel.text = @"Purchase Error!";
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
```

The last two cases, plus the default, are giving me the following error:

> Cannot jump from switch statement to this case label

I have used the switch statement many, many times; this is the first time I have seen this.   The code has been copied from a tutorial ([here](http://xcodenoobies.blogspot.com/2012/04/implementing-inapp-purchase-in-xcode.html)), which I am trying to adapt for my app.  Would appreciate the help on this one.  SD

Comment: Could you pls try putting the interiors of all the `case` blocks in curly braces and see if that changes anything? Like this: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch01.html#EXswitch

Comment: You can't declare `NSError *error = nil;` inside the case without enclosing it in a block (curly braces)

Answer (score 235, accepted):

C is not Swift. You'll be happier if you structure your `switch` statements using curly braces round all of the cases interiors, like [this](http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch01.html#EXswitch):

```
switch (tag) {
    case 1: { // curly braces
        // ...
        break;
    }
    case 2: {  // curly braces
        // ...
        break;
    }
    case 3: {  // curly braces
        // ...
        break;
    }
}
```

The extra level of curly braces allows you to do things you can't do otherwise.

Comment: Unbelievable!  I was unable to see the "trees in the forest".  I knew this, just unable to think of it... thanks Matt  SD

Comment: One of many reasons why I never use `switch` in C... :) Too many traps for my taste.

Comment: I stumbled on this error and answer when using a C++ reinterpret_cast <...> in a switch statement - apparently the angle brackets threw off the parser in the same way. Sheesh & thanks!

Comment: around default as well?